# how to redirect index.html#/abc/ to newpage.aspx

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have a problem with trying to make some redirections from an old HTML page which was reading some parameters from the URL to feed some flash components to a new ASPX page.

The issue is that the page URLs are of the form: http://www.mysite.com/index.html#/abc/
and that needs to redirect to something like: http://www.mysite.com/new-abc.aspx

There are several different values following the # but in essence they are all the same html page. Other problem is that the values are not even passed in a query string.

I'm using Windows Server 2008, IIS 7 (not R2) and I have installed the URL Rewrite module but so far my rules have not worked.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!!
Jose

Comment: Which url rewrite module you are using. And can you paste your rules here?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, please someone corrects me if I am wrong, you cannot get anchors (#...) from back-end. So if you have a URL rewriting module it won't work.

But you can use javascript to do that. Get the anchor value from the javascript, and then redirect your document from javascript. here is an example:

```
var anc = location.hash;
if (anc )
   document.location = "/blabla/" + anc + "/test.aspx";
```